# Setting up Mongoose with provided demo not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hey all,
I'm very new to mongodb, mongoose and node.js. I would like to create a little demo to see how mongoose works. After installing (and testing the correctes of) node.js I downloaded mongoose and tried the following code (also provided on the mongoose website):

```
require.paths.unshift('vendor/mongoose');
var mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;

mongoose.model('User', {

properties: ['first', 'last', 'age', 'updated_at'],

cast: {
  age: Number,
  'nested.path': String
},

indexes: ['first'],

setters: {
    first: function(v){
        return this.v.capitalize();
    }
},

getters: {
    full_name: function(){ 
        return this.first + ' ' + this.last 
    }
},

methods: {
    save: function(fn){
        this.updated_at = new Date();
        this.__super__(fn);
    }
},

static: {
    findOldPeople: function(){
        return this.find({age: { '$gt': 70 }});
    }
}

});

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');

var User = db.model('User');

var u = new User();
u.name = 'John';
u.save(function(){
sys.puts('Saved!');
});

User.find({ name: 'john' }).all(function(array){

});
```

The problem is that when I run node myfile.js I got the following error:

```
node.js:181
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
at Function._load (module.js:266:25)
at require (module.js:364:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/my/path/to/mongoose+node test/myfile.js:2:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:420:26)
at Object..js (module.js:426:10)
at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:439:10)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:173:26)
```

Now, I have to say again that I'm really new to this, so my folder called "mongoose+node test" has inside only the mongoose folder which contains a bunch of JavaScript files, and of course myfile.js. Am I maybe missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version, you don't need to use `.Mongoose` .

Just replace the following :

`var mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;`

with:

`var mongoose = require('mongoose')`

Comment: yea that would be the later step. For now it's pretty evident that your npm didn't install correctly. After which you have to install mongoose and then come to this.

Comment: I did everything and it still doesn't work :/. Don't know where to go now.

Comment: when you ran `npm install mongoose`, did it install correctly? did you get `npm ok` message ?

Comment: I received something like this: 
`mongoose@1.3.0 ./node_modules/mongoose`
then I retried and now seems to be installed correctly (got some colored output that seemed correct). Now the error changed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It can't find mongoose. The easiest way to deal with this is to install it through [`npm`](http://npmjs.org/).

To intall npm:

`curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

To install mongoose:

`npm install mongoose`

You also have to download and install mongoDB and start a mongoDB server.

The [`unix quickstart`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix) will help you install, run and test mongoDB.

Your main problem is that `require.paths` should not be edited. You should be requiring an url directly or going through a package system. In the [nodejs docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/all.html#loading_from_the_require.paths_Folders) it states `require.paths` should be avoided.

Personally I would recommend you stick to `npm` as it's the de-factor standard.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I already have mongoose as stated in the topic, I downloaded it and also installed I guess. Anyhow I tried the curl operation and I got some error (npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/.cache/npm/0.3.18/package.tgz
npm ERR! Failed creating the tarball.). Thanks for the tip on installing MongoDB and starting the server, I thought it was already embedded in mongoose.

Comment: @Masiar do `sudo curl` and `sudo npm`. Like I mentioned it doesn't like you when you use `require.paths`, I've had issues with it myself and I just stick to using `npm`.

Comment: I tried cURLing with sudo but I got the same error: npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/.cache/npm/0.3.18/package.tgz
npm ERR! Failed creating the tarball.
npm ERR! couldn't pack /var/folders/EM/EMWiGx5-FK8FxV6+BNs-L++++TI/-Tmp-/npm-1303554226811/1303554226811-0.20846882415935397/contents/package to /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/.cache/npm/0.3.18/package.tgz

Comment: @Masiar you are in linux right? Try downloading the npm source and building it.

Comment: @Raynos: I'm on OS X, in the meantime I'm downloading MongoDB from the website you linked (although you linked the Linux installation ;).

Comment: @Raynos: I installed MongoDB (checked, it runs), then I installed npm and did sudo npm install mongoose, no error found. But still, when I tried to run my program I always get the same error. Any help?

Comment: you need to sudo install mongoose in the same directory that your code file is in and you need to remove that   `require.paths.unshift` line.